# Sencha touch List items drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, sencha-touch-2

I need to implement drag and drop feature for dataview,list in sencha touch. I followed https://github.com/kostysh/Drag-Drop-example-for-Sencha-Touch and it's good for container items. But please help me about dataview.list scrolling.

Thanx in advance.